# Export just a function from js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

I have two modules one written in `ts` the other one in `js`. One of the utilities in `js` module need to be accessed in `ts` module.

So utility `service.js` as follows,

```
module.exports = {
    helloFriends: function (message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}

console.log('This part should not get invoked');
```

The called `caller.ts` as follows,

```
import { helloFriends } from './../moduleb/service';


helloFriends('Hello');
```

The output of above `tsc caller.ts` then `node caller.js` outputs following,

```
This part should not get invoked
Hello
```

I don't want any other code to get invoked from `service.js` except the function `helloFriends`, What can I do?

***Note:*** Both modules are separate from each other with their own node dependencies.

***Update:1***

I handled with a hack, I defined `IAM` in both the modules `.env` files.

For `service.js` `.env` has `IAM=service`,
For `caller.ts` `.env` has `IAM=caller`,

So if `service.js` is called from its own module `IAM` is `service` but when it is called from outside e.g. from `caller.ts` it has `IAM` value as `caller` then in `service.js` I made following changes:

In `service.js` I made changes as follows:

```
var iam = process.env.IAM;
module.exports = {
        helloFriends: function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        }
    }
    
if (iam === 'service') {
    console.log('This part should not get invoked, When called by external modules other than service');
}
```

So based on caller configuration I decide whether to execute a particular code section or not.

The plugin used for `.env` https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

***Update:2***

Based on learnings I had after this question better approach would be to have functions to serve each purpose/functionality & export them individually.

Comment: While downvoting adding comment will help, Thanks

Comment: Not my downvote, but what have you tried already? Can't you just remove the code, or place it in a method that is exported?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but AFAIK this isn't possible. I believe `require`/`import` will run through the contents of the file which includes execution of any function calls. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37325716/3813411

Comment: Caramiriel & rb612 thanks for suggestions it helped me to deduce the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is hinted at by this question: [How does require() in node.js work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475792/how-does-require-in-node-js-work). In the question the asker has the following code in a module:

```
// mod.js
var a = 1;
this.b = 2;
exports.c = 3;
```

When mod.js is imported, the following properties are set:

```
// test.js
var mod = require('./mod.js');
console.log(mod.a);    // undefined
console.log(mod.b);    // 2
console.log(mod.c);    // 3
```

The this/exports difference is interesting by itself, but it also tells us that the whole module is being run when it is required/imported and as it is stated in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477787/8183900) you can even return part way through the module code.

This means that your `console.log('This part should not get invoked');` will unfortunately be invoked unless you have a way of exiting the module code

Answer (score 0):

***Update:1***

I handled with a hack, I defined `IAM` in both the modules `.env` files.

For `service.js` `.env` has `IAM=service`,
For `caller.ts` `.env` has `IAM=caller`,

So if `service.js` is called from its own module `IAM` is `service` but when it is called from outside e.g. from `caller.ts` it has `IAM` value as `caller` then in `service.js` I made following changes:

In `service.js` I made changes as follows:

```
var iam = process.env.IAM;
module.exports = {
        helloFriends: function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        }
    }
    
if (iam === 'service') {
    console.log('This part should not get invoked, When called by external modules other than service');
}
```

So based on caller configuration I decide whether to execute a particular code section or not.

The plugin used for `.env` https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

***Update:2***

Based on learnings I had after this question better approach would be to have functions to serve each purpose/functionality & export them individually.