# Why Firebase re-init when importing from multiple files anyway?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I know we can use firebase.apps.length to check whether the Firebase is initiated or not.

Eg:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
   firebase.initializeApp({});
}

export default firebase;
```

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/1999

However, I read another question on StackOverflow that if we import the same file multiple times, it just runs once ([Does ES6 module importing execute the code inside the imported file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325667/does-es6-module-importing-execute-the-code-inside-the-imported-file))

So the question is why Firebase behaves like that? I mean if this post is true: [Does ES6 module importing execute the code inside the imported file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325667/does-es6-module-importing-execute-the-code-inside-the-imported-file), then we don't need to check ***firebase.apps.length*** in the first place because it just runs once no matter how many times we import it

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use that code to check if Firebase is initialized.  Most of the time people just initialize once in a known location, and assume from that point on that it is going to be available later.

If you're in a situation where some code might run repeatedly (like a function call), then you might want to do that check **if you want to initialize Firebase lazily**.